# Android Kotlin Moshi Custom Json Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

Ok so i have the following Json Pojo:

```
data class JCategory(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val image: String?,
        val color: String?,
        val categories: List<JCategory>?,
        val products: List<JProduct>?
)
```

And i want to write a customs deserialiser, so the final object will look like this:

```
data class Category(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val image: String?,
        val color: String?,
        val list: List<Any>
)
```

Basically, the mappings are:

- `JCategory -> Category`
- `JProduct -> Prod1 / Prod2` based on some value inside JProduct

The JCategory two lists will be joint into 1, in which will contain more JCategory plus Prod1/Prod2.

Is this a valid and efficient way of mapping the data in this adapter according to Moshi?

```
@FromJson fun fromJson(category: JCategory): CategoryProduct {    

        val prods = category.products
        val cats = category.categories

        val list = mutableListOf<Any>()

        if (prods != null && prods.size > 0) {
            prods.forEach {
                list.add(if (it.isMain == 1) {
                    P1(
                            ...
                    )
                } else {
                    P2(
                            ...
                    )
                })
            }
        }

        if (cats != null && cats.size > 0){
            cats.forEach {
                list.add(fromJson(it))
            }
        }

        return CategoryProduct(
                category.id,
                category.name,
                category.image.emptyToNull(),
                parsedColor,
                category.parentId,
                list
        )
    }
```

Notice that i have a JCategory and inside a list of the same object,
so i thought the Adapter would parse this automatically but it doesn't. So i tried `list.add(fromJson(it))` and it worked.

So my questions are:

- is `list.add(fromJson(it))` the proper way of handling cases like this?
- how can i map an object to another one/other based on some property inside it? The fromJson can only return 1 type of transformed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, recursion is proper way of handling `list(add(fromJson(it))`, the main problem is inside the structure. The structure itself is recursive. Proper way is to flatten structure & referencing to another object type.

About second, this is also problem which comes with bad structure. You can solve this by common parent via inheritance. Then check target type itself.

```
interface X { }
data class A : X { }
data class B : X { }
@FromJson fun fromJson(json: C): X {  }
```